# WCF Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, wcf, streaming

I am trying to upload data files to a WCF service and it is working fine with small files. However when I try to upload a file with size of 2MB I just get an error 400 Bad Request.

Since it is working for small files, I have to think that there is an issue with max sizes restrictions, but I have increased them all, and I still get the same error.

I appreciate your help to guide me to the right direction. Thanks :)

I am using the following configuration in the WCF Service.

This is the Service configuration

```
 <!-- WIZARD FILE UPLOAD CONFIGURATION -->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="BBS.eBillity.Services.ServiceBehavior" name="BBS.eBillity.Services.Modules.IWizardUploadFile">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WizardUploadFile_StreamedBinding"
     contract="BBS.eBillity.Services.Contracts.ServicesContracts.IWizardUploadFile">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
```

The Binding configuration for the service

```
<binding name="WizardUploadFile_StreamedBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="StreamedRequest" closeTimeout="04:01:00"
 openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"   useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
           maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
```

The service contract, very simple...

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWizardUploadFile
{

    [OperationContract]
    void UploadFiletoServer(Stream request);

}
```

Inside the system.web tag I added the following in the client and server configuration file

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

This is the client configuration:

```
 <basicHttpBinding>

 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWizardUploadFile" closeTimeout="04:01:00"
 openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00"
 allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      transferMode="Streamed"
 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
   <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
       maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
       maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
   <security mode="None">
     <transport clientCredentialType="None"
             proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
     <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
   </security>
 </binding>
```

Endpoint configuration

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:1234/WCFeBillity/WizardUploadFile.svc"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWizardUploadFile"
contract="WizardUploadFile.IWizardUploadFile" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWizardUploadFile" />
```

Comment: Try enabling tracing at the server side. That may have some information why the request is being rejected.

Comment: I do not know if transferMode="StreamedRequest" is a valid value, it think it should be transferMode="Streamed"